# How do I equip the M19?

Tags: pc, resident-evil-7

I've just fixed the broken gun to get the M19, but I can't seem to equip it?

If I stow the original pistol away, I just get nothing for slot 2?

Comment: are you having troubles with fixing it with repair kit or with equipping it from your inventory?

Comment: The latter, I've already fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To equip it go into your inventory and move into one of the top slots.  <kbd>R</kbd> is default control on keyboard  (and <kbd>X</kbd> if you are using XBOX controller) to select it and then move with arrow keys.

You can have both pistols equipped and assigned to different buttons.

See [game guide](http://game.capcom.com/manual/re7/en/windows/page/4/1)